# Duplicate Record display in Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm working on software everything work perfectly, but when I print its record from multiple table is show duplicate entry for each row

I have no idea why this thing happened.

Here is my Query which gets data from table and display using `PHP`

```
Select item_id,item_name,rci.item_shape,
remaing_quantity,rci.child_date from rads_childrenitem rci ,
add_itemchildren aic where aic.id = rci.item_id group by
rci.id,item_name,rci.item_shape, remaing_quantity order by rci.id desc
```

Image attached for better understanding.

[image: Click to view image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - There are some pretty fundamental faux pas in your query although in this instance I suspect that the problem lies in your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your SQL to using JOIN rather than using multiple tables in the FROM clause.  Also the group by MAY be wrong (can't test it without using your data), but in any case, try this...

```
Select item_id,item_name,rci.item_shape,
        remaing_quantity,rci.child_date 
    from rads_childrenitem rci
    join add_itemchildren aic on aic.id = rci.item_id 
    group by item_id, item_name,rci.item_shape, remaing_quantity 
    order by rci.id desc
```

Note that I've changed the group from rci.id to item_id.

Also the field child_date should either be in your group by or something like MAX() or MIN().  You may also want to change the order by to item_id.

Comment: It's show error

"Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'inventory_system.rci.child_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: Sorry - that was in the updated answer - either put rci.child_date in group by or do something like max/min on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have those multiple records in your database. "Stock-Out Date to Dhoku-Hassu" is different values 500 and 200. Your GROUP BY does not group them, because it is different values

Comment: Which column in database is "Stock-Out Date to Dhoku-Hassu"? and it would be nice if you show your code how you create the table, not only sql.

Comment: in Database, it's in "dhk_children" table and column name is "stockout_date" 
would you please guide me how can I share my code with you...

Comment: Dear here is complete project please check in this folder my database with code avalible and file name is table_childrenItem.php

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz9jx3O-rld3MnRYa25wMzFMQmc?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Add DISTINCT in your query.

```
Select DISTINCT (item_id)
     , item_name
     , rci.item_shape
     , remaing_quantity
     , rci.child_date 
  from rads_childrenitem rci 
     , add_itemchildren aic 
 where aic.id = rci.item_id 
 group 
    by item_name
     ,rci.id
     , item_name
     , rci.item_shape
     , remaing_quantity 
 order 
    by rci.id desc
```

Read more about it from here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: it's Show error when I run this Querry:
"Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'inventory_system.rci.id' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT"